# Getting an error when using the code shrinker 'R8' on Android Release Build

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I’m getting the error below when i set the code shrinker to ‘R8’.
I am using proguard on "Debug" but I want to use R8 on my release build.

It is building but closing automatically after installing the app.

here's the errors.

`Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn’t find class “com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider” on path: DexPathList[[zip file “/data/app/com.nkkinsoft.modernmom-1/base.apk”],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.nkkinsoft.modernmom-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.nkkinsoft.modernmom-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]`

I already tried adding these to my AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<meta-data android:value="ca-app-pub-8659477468618951~2757166332"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"></meta-data>
```

Thanks.

Comment: R8 uses your proguard file(s), are you excluding MobileAdsInitProvider from being stripped.

Comment: I don't know how if that is excluded it is working fine on proguard but on debug mode.

Comment: How can i include that?

Comment: `-keep public class MyClass` see the official docs https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#keep-code

Comment: I tried that and it seems not working having same errors
I also did the solution from this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54184851/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-com-google-android-gms-ads/54501907#54501907

Comment: Did you add the `com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID` of meta-data in manifest like following link https://stackoverflow.com/a/53013453/10627299

Comment: Yes I added it.

Comment: I recommand you to use Custom Linker Configuration : take a look at this tutorial: https://progrunning.net/fixing-xamarin-forms-linker-issues/

Comment: @JanGenvherPapica did you find a solution?